# Concatenate string and range function in pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, dataframe, concatenation

I have a pandas dataframe with a number of columns. I want to add a new one with a fixed prefix that is a string and a suffix that is a range of integers.

The output I would like is as below, where each row in 'new column' is populated with an integer suffix. The suffix is *not* dependent on the index of the dataframe.

| Column A | new column |
| --- | --- |
| x | ABCD_1 |
| y | ABCD_2 |

I was thinking of the below code

```
dataframe['new colum'] = 'ABCD_' + str(range(z + 1, z + 1 + len(another_dataframe)))
```

But that will return (if we say that the length of another dataframe is 2 and z is 1)

```
ABCD_range(2, 4)
```

for every row. I was also thinking of using `apply` but if I do

```
dataframe['new colum'] = dataframe.apply(lambda row: 'ABCD_'+ str(range(1, 1 + len(another_dataframe)), axis=1)
```

I get the same results as before.

Can't this be done in a single line to add that extra column?

Answer (score 0):

In (almost) one line you can do this:

```
lenght = dataframe.shape[0]
dataframe["new_column"] = list(map(''.join, zip(["ABCD_"]*lenght, [str(x) for x in range(lenght)])))
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. I changed the range to ```range(z + 1, z + 1 +len(another_dataframe))``` to make it start at the right integer.